# "Unable to execute 'go list'' command, run 'go mod tidy' to know more" Error in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Sorry if this is a silly question - just getting started with Go.

I have installed 'go 1.13' (due to this being the version currently supported by [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime)) and the latest version for the VSCode [Go extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go). This is all in Windows.

I then followed the [Go Getting Started Guide](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started). All seems to be working fine - I can run the application and VSCode does not report any syntax errors etc.

[image: Go source in VSCode]

Now VSCode just gives me a nagging error message whenever I open a `.go` or `.mod` file:

> Unable to execute 'go list'' command, run 'go mod tidy' to know more

[image: Go VSCode Error]

Running the `go mod tidy` command does not result in any output. The other tools, such as gopls where installed successfully by VSCode. Any idea what could cause this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Somehow thinking this could be related to using Go version 1.13 since the VSCode extension I think recommended 1.14+. But if that is the case would be interested how best to develop for Cloud Functions then and version 1.13.

Comment: So you're running an extension that does not support your go version.  The error message is from the extension.  Seems like your options are to ignore the message, or remove the extension (you've already said you can't upgrade your go version),

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've validated that I am getting the same error when updating to Go 1.16.3 (latest on the download page). The extension installs all its tools successfully `gopkgs
  go-outline
  dlv
  staticcheck
  gopls` but I still get the error message.

Comment: Looking closely at the error message, it also appears as if this may be more directly related to the 'Dependency Analysis' Extension: redhat.fabric8-analytics. Disabling that definitely makes the error message disappear.

Comment: to spread the love would be good if this issue got sent to owners of that extension ... just say'n

Comment: Yeah, good point! Issue raised for the extension https://github.com/fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension/issues/506

Comment: If possible, switch to Cloud Run https://cloud.google.com/run

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the 'Dependency Analysis' extension ([redhat.fabric8-analytics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.fabric8-analytics)). Disabling this extension will result in the error not being shown anymore.

This error is also listed in the FAQ for the Dependency Analysis extension:

FAQ Item 3: Failed to run golist command.

> **Suggestion**: Resolve the error thrown by go mod tidy and go list for the project and try again.

Maybe this will work for someone else but it didn't work for me (only disabling the extension did). In any case, I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension/issues/506) at the extensions GitHub rep [fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension](https://github.com/fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension) to see if there is another fix but disabling the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just install the latest version(1.16.3) and work for me.